# Stateful Structured Spark Streaming: Timeout is not getting triggered

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I've set the timeout duration to "2 minutes" as follows:

```
  def updateAcrossEvents (tuple3: Tuple3[String, String, String], inputs: Iterator[R00tJsonObject],
                          oldState: GroupState[MyState]): OutputRow = {

    println("$$$$ Inside updateAcrossEvents with : " + tuple3._1 + ", " + tuple3._2 + ", " + tuple3._3)
    var state: MyState = if (oldState.exists) oldState.get else MyState(tuple3._1, tuple3._2, tuple3._3)

    if (oldState.hasTimedOut) {
      println("@@@@@ oldState has timed out @@@@")
      // Logic to Write OutputRow
      OutputRow("some values here...")
    } else {
      for (input <- inputs) {
        state = updateWithEvent(state, input)
        oldState.update(state)
        oldState.setTimeoutDuration("2 minutes")
      }
      OutputRow(null, null, null)
    }

  }
```

I have also specified ProcessingTimeTimeout in 'mapGroupsWithState' as follows...

```
.mapGroupsWithState(GroupStateTimeout.ProcessingTimeTimeout())(updateAcrossEvents)
```

But 'hasTimedOut' is never true so I don't get any output! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it only works if input data is continuously flowing. I had stopped the input job because I had enough data but it seems timeouts work only if the data is continuously fed. Not sure why it's designed that way. Makes it a bit harder to write unit/integration tests BUT I am sure there's a reason why it's designed this way. Thanks.